# How to pass multiple strings to a python program

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu

Just for fun I made a very simple Python program:

```
var = "bello"
pas = raw_input("insert password\n")
if(pas==var):
    print("\naccess granted\n")
    print("\ncool information")
else:
    print("\naccess denied")
```

Now I tried to brute force access using crunch, with the shell on ubuntu terminal:

```
crunch 1 5 | python pex.py
```

pex.py is the name of the program. But it doesn't work, I suspect that the execution of the program does not iterate, but i have no idea how to make this brute force attack work.
Can you help me? Better with a complete explaination.

Comment: the question is: if i found myself in front of a program like the one i show, how can i bruteforce the password control?

Comment: `crunch` output a list of words, you have to iterate its output using bash and for each iteration run your python script. https://superuser.com/questions/284187/bash-iterating-over-lines-in-a-variable

Comment: this is actually a bash question by the way. the python has not to be edited.

Comment: ok, and what is the bash code, in this case, to to iterate its output and for each iteration run pex.py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First output crunch to file. This has the side benefit you can actually check what crunch has generated. You might however skip the file.

```
crunch 1 5 >> pas.txt
```

Load the file into environment array (BASH 4 example)

```
readarray pas_a < ./pas.txt
```

Execute once per password

```
   for pas in "${pas_a[@]}"
   do
       ./python pex.py "$pas" &
   done < ./pas.txt
```

Remove the & to make it sequential rather than parallel.

Clean the array from environment if you like.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of taking `raw_input`, get the arguments passed when the program is called with `sys.argv`.

```
pas = argv[1]
```

Then, when you call `python pex.py <password>`, `pas` will get set to `<password>`.

### Note

If the password is multiple words, this won't work. You'll need to join the contents of `sys.argv` (excluding the 0th element, that's the program name) with `' '.join()`.

```
pas = ' '.join(argv[1:])
```

Comment: Python has not to be edited. The python is a bogus example. OP intent is to bruteforce a program. You can't edit the program to make it custom bruteforce-able. The goal is rather to find a way to feed the single password and iterate.

Comment: yes, i prefer you to not edit my program to make it more esely brutforceable, it's a bit like cheating